# Android App - get location of picture when uploading it to a database/server

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation, location

I am trying to save the location of picture when it is uploaded to a server. I have two options (Camera and Gallery) to take the picture with camera and to upload picture from Gallery of your phone.

I am also a bit confused which location should I take; of the phone or of the picture, and which one I can get/extract?

I have seen few examples online such as:

```
final ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(String.valueOf(filePath));
      float[] LatLong = new float[2];
      if (exifInterface.getLatLong(LatLong)) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + LatLong[0] + "\nLong: " + LatLong[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but they do not work.

Would you have any additional tips?

Also on the topic "which location should I get/save/extract,the one of device the moment the picture is taken or picture. Does the picture that is saved in gallery have its own location stored too?

Thank you in advance

Comment: why do you need location forpicture?

Comment: I want to get the location where the picture was taken so it can be stored in database/server, used later on for different options. also so that user does not need to specify where the picture was taken

Comment: you get false on your `if` ?

Comment: the whole thing is in try-catch and it always goes to catch; but I am also not sure what ExitInterface is;

I am getting .png images, and in ExitIterface spec. they are mentioning only .jpeg types, is that the problem maybe?

Comment: I mean that function `exifInterface.getLatLong(LatLong)` return boolean, it return true or false?

Comment: Yeah it passes the first line (ExitInterface) and then does not enter the if, so the Boolean is false;;; I have two options to put in the () of the first line. either the URI of the image or the file of the image, when I put the File of the image it goes until the if statement; if i put URI, it goes to catch statement, with a message "no such file or directory"